# IBM Java Runtime Environment on CentOS

Tags: centos, software-installation, java

I need to install IBM's JRE, but I can't seem to find an appropriate download or guide to installing it on CentOS. I've found various zips, but none of them include an RPM and I have no idea where to start with the files contained inside the zips.

If somebody knew of a guide and an appropriate download, as the developerWorks one seems to be down, it says that IBM Developer Works is currently down for maintenance. It seems to have been like this for quite some time, so I don't think IBM are going to fix it any time soon.

Also, I'm downloading the IBM version to run a minecraft server, as I've hear that IBM's version consumes a lot less RAM and such.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use an RPM.  Java is distributed as pre-compiled executables anyway, without targeting any particular distribution; I believe the only external libraries it depends are the core C libraries.

So you just pick 32 or 64 bit.  I haven't used the IBM JRE, but if it is packaged similarly to the Oracle JRE, it is politely all kept together in its own directory (which means you must add links to the executables you want to use, probably at least `java` and `jar`, or add the `/bin` directory to your $PATH).

Presumably there is a bit of documentation about this in the tarball, you have to register to download so I did not check:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/linux/download.html

The "64-bit AMD/Opteron/EM64T" should be the equivalent of a x86_64 RPM.  The "POWER" and "System z" ones are for IBM architectures.

Comment: I have a DeveloperWorks account and it still won't let me access that page, after I've signed in. I don't know what's happening or whether they are going to fix it. I can't seem to get a hold of a decent version.

Comment: @ConnerStephenMcCabe The site's working fine for me after I logged in. Try clearing your cache/cookies/etc.